# Nested dictionary to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to get my nested dictionary (that's created by a for-loop) into pandas.

```
list_of_instruments = ["Gold", "Nasdaq", "Dow Jones", "SP500"]
instruments = {}
for instrument in list_of_instruments:
    instruments[instrument] = {'ig_name': "", 'latest_close': 0, 'latest_close_date': 0, 'intraday_bid': 0}

df = pd.DataFrame(instruments).T
print(df)
```

gives me the following

```
          ig_name latest_close latest_close_date intraday_bid
OMXS30                       0                 0            0
Nasdaq                       0                 0            0
Dow Jones                    0                 0            0
SP500                        0                 0            0
```

Which is basically what I want, with the slight problem that the first column doesn't get named. I've tried several different solutions but just can't come up with something that works. Rather sure there's a somewhat easy solution to this (that doesn't involve transposing the dataframe as I do with ".T" as well). I just can't seem to get it.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: `first column doesn't get named` - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Because that's `index`.
You can set the `index name` as: `df.index.name = 'Index Column'`

**OUTPUT**:

```py
             ig_name latest_close latest_close_date intraday_bid
Index Column                                                    
Gold                            0                 0            0
Nasdaq                          0                 0            0
Dow Jones                       0                 0            0
SP500                           0                 0            0
```

Or if you want, you can have the first column as a separate column with integer based index:

```py
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Index Column'})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
  Index Column ig_name latest_close latest_close_date intraday_bid
0         Gold                    0                 0            0
1       Nasdaq                    0                 0            0
2    Dow Jones                    0                 0            0
3        SP500                    0                 0            0
```

Comment: Now I feel very dumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The *first column* as you said, idn't one, it's the `index`, you can name it, or set the index to a numeric one, and your instrument names becomes a real column like the others

- set index name

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(instruments).T
  df.index.name = 'instrument'

             ig_name latest_close latest_close_date intraday_bid
  instrument
  Gold                          0                 0            0
  Nasdaq                        0                 0            0
  Dow Jones                     0                 0            0
  SP500                         0                 0            0
  ```
- remove from being the index

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(instruments).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'instrument'})

    instrument ig_name latest_close latest_close_date intraday_bid
  0       Gold                    0                 0            0
  1     Nasdaq                    0                 0            0
  2  Dow Jones                    0                 0            0
  3      SP500                    0                 0            0
  ```

---

Or build your data differently

```
instruments = [
    {'instrument': i, 'ig_name': "", 'latest_close': 0, 'latest_close_date': 0, 'intraday_bid': 0}
    for i in list_of_instruments
]

df = pd.DataFrame(instruments)

  instrument ig_name  latest_close  latest_close_date  intraday_bid
0       Gold                     0                  0             0
1     Nasdaq                     0                  0             0
2  Dow Jones                     0                  0             0
3      SP500                     0                  0             0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(instruments, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_of_instruments = ["Gold", "Nasdaq", "Dow Jones", "SP500"]
n = len(list_of_instruments)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ig_name': list_of_instruments, 
                   'latest_close': np.zeros(n), 
                   'latest_close_date': np.zeros(n), 
                   'intraday_bid': np.zeros(n)})
print(df)
```

You're using as an `index` your `list_of_instruments`, which seems that is not what you want.